# Find a function that satisfies $f(\sin(x))+f(\cos(x))=\left(\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}\right)^2$

Tags: calculus

Find a function $f:\mathbb{R}^*\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such as $f>0$ and it satisfies the following equation: $$f(\sin(x))+f(\cos(x))=\left(\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}\right)^2,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{\frac{k\pi}{2},k\pi\;k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} $$
I don't know how to start this, any idea would be helpful.

Comment: I'd start with some identities; see what you can get out of $\sin(2x)$.

Comment: If one wants to find more than one solution then it's useful to note that if $f$ is a solution then so is $f+g$ if $g(\sin(x)) + g(\cos(x)) = 0$. For example $g(x) = C\left[\frac{1}{2} - x^2\right]$ has this property (one also have to make sure that $f+g>0$ is satisfied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\left(\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}\right)^2=\frac{1}{\sin^2x}+\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\left(\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{\sin x \cos x}\right)^2 = \frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\sin^2 x \cos^2 x} = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}+\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$$

Comment: That's a pretty big hint :)

Comment: You're right, so I put it in bold ;-D.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(\sin x)+f(\cos x)=\frac{1}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}$$
one solution is the set of all function with property
$$f(x)+f(y)=\frac{1}{x^2y^2}$$
where $x^2+y^2=1$.

Another, with
$$f(\sin x)+f(\cos x)=\frac{1}{\sin^2x}+\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$$
is the set of all function with property
$$f(x)+f(y)=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}$$
where $x^2+y^2=1$.

Better is that take $\sin x=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos x=\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ thus
$$f(\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2})+f(\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})=\frac{(1+t^2)^2}{2t(1-t^2)}$$